# How to draw a resized image to a rect on Dart

Tags: html5-canvas, dart, game-engine

I'm trying to code some animations to my [GameEngine](https://github.com/foxxor/crystalrift-dart), what I've done so far is use sprite-sets with all the possible frames of the element I'm animating, for this I use the [drawImageToRect](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CanvasRenderingContext2D.html#drawImageToRect) method and it works pretty well. However now I want not only to draw a piece of the image but also I want to resize the image and draw only a piece of it.

[image]

Checking the documentation I notice there's a method to draw a resized image [drawImageScaledFromSource](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CanvasRenderingContext2D.html#drawImageScaledFromSource) but this only allows me to draw the complete image and resize it. Which is not convenient since I want to handle animations in a single file and if I'd have to manually resize the same animation image multiple times to handle different sizes.

Is possible to resize and image AND draw only a piece of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[drawImageScaledFromSource](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CanvasRenderingContext2D.html#drawImageScaledFromSource) that you mention in your question seems to provide what you want. See the example attached to the documentation :

```dart
VideoElement video = document.query('video');
video.width = 100;
video.height = 100;
// Take the middle 20x20 pixels from the video and stretch them.
ctx.drawImageScaledFromSource(video, 40, 40, 20, 20, 50, 50, 100, 100);
```

The four source parameters allow to take any portion of the source.

Comment: You're right, I think I need some sleep lol. That did the trick, the "video.width" part is not necessary since you're indicating the sourceWidth and sourceHeight in the call.